# How do I migrate boot+root LVM onto another drive

Tags: linux, debian, lvm

Here's my block devices layout:

```
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sda1                          8:1    0   3.7T  0 part /media/Toshiba4TB
sdb                             8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1                          8:17   0   2.7T  0 part /media/Failing3TB
sdc                             8:32   0 298.1G  0 disk
├─sdc1                          8:33   0   243M  0 part
├─sdc2                          8:34   0     1K  0 part
└─sdc5                          8:37   0 297.9G  0 part
  ├─RIVENDELL--SVR--vg-root   254:0    0   250G  0 lvm  /
  ├─RIVENDELL--SVR--vg-swap_1 254:1    0    12G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─RIVENDELL--SVR--vg-boot   254:2    0   200M  0 lvm  /boot
sdd                             8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk
└─sdd1                          8:49   0   5.5T  0 part /media/SeagateIronWolf6TB
```

sdc is my main OS drive which is coming up with SMART errors/bad sectors, so I'm looking to migrate it onto another (2TB) drive. Last time I tried this I added a mirror (RAID 1, not LVM, using KVPM) there might have been some errors mirroring, but the main problem was rebooting failed, went into GRUB rescue and I didn't have a clue where to go from there. fortunately earlier this year I had some success cloning (ddrescue) off of a similar drive having the same problem, so I reverted to that drive and restored files from a backup to get my main server software back in sync with where it was.

For a while now I've been looking into trying to find a way to get it off LVM back to physical partitions, so a simple clone would be easy in future. I'm warming to the idea of retaining the LVM partitions perhaps mirroring the failing volume to a working drive so when it fails completely I can throw in another drive to retain resiliency. Can anyone help me, as so far the google search results I've been following left me with the unbootable RAID mentioned above (I think it had a problem with MDM or something)?

Comment: I would use clonezilla , clone the failing disk into a new one and substitute the failing disk with the new one.

Comment: Yes, that's my backup plan, but I would love to throw in a new hard drive, migrate partitions, and remove the old one, knowing the server would just start back up again.

Comment: That's exactly what it will do.

Comment: Although with LVM, assuming the harddrive was already attached, this would be possible without any server downtime (until I tested a reboot). Previously I have used Clonezilla to clone this LVM drive, and had a few complications, so I'm primarily looking to find a way of moving the boot partition and boot sector off an LVM drive.